# gradle local jar dependency not working

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

I am pretty new to gradle.
This is my project configuration

```
Project
.
├── build.gradle
├── sub-project-1
│   ├── build.gradle
├── tests
│   ├── rest
│   └── unit
│       ├── build.gradle // Lets call this unit_build.gradle
```

My unit tests have a dependency on derby.jar, and the unit_build.gradle has the following:

```
dependencies{
    ..
    testCompile fileTree(dir: "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../db/lib", include: "derby.jar") 
    testCompile fileTree(dir: "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../db/lib", include: "derbyclient.jar") 
}
```

Note: We have our own repository and derby is not included in that. So we use it by adding it from local.

This works fine when I run a gradle build, followed by my test task.

But we also publish the jar to a test server and run it there where it fails with a class not found exception on derby.

What can be the reason? What should be done to fix this?

Gradle version - 1.12

Answer (score 1):

this happens because you choose wrong target dependency configuration. I mean `testCompile`, instead of this you should use: `testRuntime` or `testRuntimeClasspath`

Comment: If it is compile, then I need not specify for runtime right? Can you explain the differences?

Comment: the main idea of existence the testCompile is just providing dependencies for compiling tests(i.e. junit) but you don't want include these dependencies in your release package, so they are will be excluded after compiling tests, and you got "Not class Def Found". See this [page](https://docs.gradle.org/1.12/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:dependency_management), section Dependency management. Also you can define your own derby as a runtime dependency.

Comment: testRuntime did not solve. testRuntimeClasspath is not in the version I am using

Comment: Where's your code located (under main or the test)? if under the main scope you should use `runtime` or the `compile`.

Comment: this is under test

Comment: Did you try, how it lives with `compile`?